# Why the first completionHandler return the data before all methods are called?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, completionhandler

Here is my API code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ItunesApi: NSObject
{
var artistArray:Array <Artist> = []

func downloadData(name:String, _ completionHandler:   @escaping (_ result: Array<Artist>) -> Void)
{
    Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=U2&entity=musicArtist").response
        { response in

        if let data = response.data
        {
           let JsonResult = JSON(data)
           self.findDiscography(data: JsonResult)

        }
        completionHandler(self.artistArray)
      }

}

func findDiscography (data: JSON)
    {
        for (subJson):(String, JSON) in data["results"]
        {
            if let artistName = subJson.1["artistName"].string
            {
                print(artistName);
                self.downloadDiscography(name: artistName)
            }
        }
    }

func downloadDiscography (name: String)
{
    Alamofire.request("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=U2&entity=album").response
        { response in
            if let data = response.data
            {
                let JsonResult = JSON(data)
                self.createDataModel(name: name, data: JsonResult)
            }

    }
}



func createDataModel (name: String, data: JSON)
{
    var albums:Array <Album> = []
    for (subJson):(String, JSON) in data["results"]
    {
        var thumbnail:String = ""
        var title:String = ""
        var year:String = ""

        if let thumbImage = subJson.1["artworkUrl60"].string
        {
            thumbnail = thumbImage;
        }
        if let titleString = subJson.1["collectionName"].string
        {
            title = titleString;
        }
        if let releaseDate = subJson.1["releaseDate"].string
        {
            year = releaseDate;
        }
        let album = Album(_thumbnail: thumbnail, _title: title, _year: year)
        albums.append(album)
    }
    let artist = Artist(_name: name, _musicStyle: "Rock", _albums: albums as NSArray);
    self.artistArray.append(artist);
}
```

}

And I call here in MyClassTableView.m

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
     if let artist = searchBar.text
     {
       self.itunesApi.downloadData(name: artist, { (array) in
            print(array);
       })
     }
}
```

Why the copmletionHandler return before all method are called? I want to return in first completionHandeler the result of all method but it return before. The self.itunesApi.downloadData return [] instead of an array filled

Comment: Add a completion handler to `downloadDiscography` and `findDiscography`.

Comment: Its not returing before *all* the methods are called. It is returning before  downloadDiscography's finishes, because downloadDiscography's implementation is asynchronous. If you don't understand that then there are millions of past questions exactly like this you can look for.

Comment: @Grunt and how I can do this? I am finding but don't understand nothing.